# Codeigniter sessions errors and workarounds

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

So after reading the documentation on the session library for CodeIgniter, I'm finding it rather confusing.

My problem has arisen from the need to store a few bits of information (a filename, a product ID and an array of colour IDs). I'm using flashdata for this bit.

I got a 502 error. Removing the `set_flashdata()` methods has stopped it, but I still need to send the data.

From what I understand, CI by default scrubs all data from superglobal arrays, so I can't use PHPs native sessions.

In addition, the documentation states the following:

> A useful aspect of the session array is that you can add your own data
>   to it and it will be stored in the user's cookie

This, I find quite confusing, PHP stores the session ID in the cookie, and the session data on the server. What does CI mean when it says it adds your own data to the cookie?

Surely I wanted this functionality I'd just store data in the cookie instead of using sessions?

Also, another part of the documentation states:

> Cookies can only hold 4KB of data, so be careful not to exceed the
>   capacity. 
>   The encryption process in particular produces a longer data string than the original so keep careful track of how much data you are storing.

Are they talking about storing my data in actual cookies? Or within the session? And how do I know if I'm using more than 4KB of data?? Is this per flashdata session? Or all data total?

So my questions (as bullet points), are:

1. When using the session library, is data stored in the cookie, or an actual session?
2. Why would I be getting a 502 error while using flashdata?
3. How do I work out how much data I'm using
4. Can the `userdata()` and `flashdata()` methods store different amounts of information?
5. Is there anyway I can use CIs session library in conjunction with PHPs native sessions?

Any more information would be appreciated. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused about what a session even is or the difference between a cookie and a session.

1. it's called the session library, and a session, because it's a server side session
2. are you aware that php has an error log and you have an ability to find the specific error, in fact that's what you should have done.?
3. you'll be fine unless you are trying to abuse the purpose of a session
4. flashdata is for flash messages, userdata is for storing data that needs to be retrieved for other purposes. your question is meaningless even if answered.
5. at the very top of the documentation "Note: The Session class does not utilize native PHP sessions. It generates its own session data, offering more flexibility for developers." I would advise against this, as it serves no purpose.

Comment: I'm not a beginner to PHP. I'm new to Codeigniter. I know sessions are stored on the server, which is why I'm confused as to why its says it stores data in the cookie. I would have checked the PHP error log, but a 502 error is a server error (Bad gateway). Googling, several people have had issues with flashdata and 502 errors. And I would prefer not to use PHP native sessions as it voids the idea of using CI.

Comment: Some people call them (sessions) server side cookies, because they are retarded and want to confuse people. I see what you mean. Do you use nginx or apache?

Comment: Also, you can look at apache's (or nginx's) error log and it will explain the 502 error

Comment: Ah, I've never heard of them referred to as server-side cookies :-/ I'm using apache, but it's coming up with a nginx 502 error (don't really know much about nginx, as come from more of a wamp/lamp environment).

Comment: Just changed my `flashdata` method calls to `userdata` methods and it seems to be working as expected. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Interesting, although I'd try to find out why you're getting nginx errors when you think it's apache handling things :p

Comment: That and flashdata and userdata server two entirely different purposes though. In case you aren't aware, flashdata is supposed to essentially clear/delete itself after it's displayed. I.e. i'd use userdata to store information I need to associate with that user and i'd use flashdata to show them a message about how they just saved their profile.

Comment: Thanks, it does make more sense now I know the purpose of it, and also now the confusing about server-side-cookies and client-side-cookies has been sorted out! I guess there's still a lot to learn.